# How do I cancel previous PPK file of amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I am in a big problem. actually I have given server details to third party extension support, in which I have provided them SFTP host xx.xx.xx.xx and username as ubuntu and PPK file.

Now I want to cancel the previous PPK file or some alternate way using which no one can misuse my server using those credentials. My Network administrator is responding negative on that. He said Nothing can be done now, Please let me know the solution for this problem, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you `ssh` into the EC2 machine as `ubuntu`?

Comment: yes upto now all is working good but I am afraid for future

Answer (score 0):

ok. Generate a new keypair. Say the keys are new.private and new.public

- ssh in to the EC2 machine as ubuntu using the old.private
- Edit `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` and replace its contents with new.public
- In another termibal, open a new ssh session as ubuntu using new.private
- If you can ssh with new.private, then no one can SFTP using the old key
- Use the new.private to ssh and sftp from now on

Comment: sir that was main user ubuntu, would this work later for ubuntu i.e. all permissions will remains same for ubuntu?

Comment: We are not changing permissions. Only access control will be affected. You may want to take an AMI of your instance before attempting this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help @helloV but my administrator is denied for my help in this process He said he can not take any risk. but thanks again for your help.

Comment: this is not a stackoverflow problem, it's a career problem.